# If the product $x_1x_2 ··· x_n$ is zero, then $x_1$ and $x_n$ are zero, is this statement true

Tags: solution-verification

Let $n$ be a natural number greater 1 and let $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ be real
numbers. Consider the following statement.

If the product $x_1x_2 ··· x_n$ is zero, then $x_1$ and $x_n$ are zero

I'm pretty sure that this statement is not true, since as long as one of these $x_i$ for which $1<i<n$ is zero then this would be some argument to suggest that the statement is false, am I correct in stating this?

Comment: A single counterexample, like $1\times 0\times 1$ is all you need to disprove the claim.

Comment: Correct: A counterexample, as you indicate, is any sequence such that at $x_1,x_n$ are nonzero but one other $x_i$ is zero.

Comment: In fact $1\le i\le n$ is as good.